VS Code can't find Python interpreter in WSL after latest update
Following the latest VS Code update I have had some problems with finding my Python interpreter. VS Code seems to be looking in my C drive for my Python install, instead of inside of WSL (Ubuntu).

I tried adding the following to my user's settings.json but it did not work.
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "WSL",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python3.12",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
      "WSL": {
        "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
        "args": []
      }
    },
    "python.venvPath": "/home/yourusername/.virtualenvs",  // Optional: if you use virtual environments
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true

Any ideas?

You're not running VSCode inside of WSL, are you?  If you aren't, then it shouldn't know about your Ubuntu drive at all.

On that note, Python is fully cross-platform compatible, as are most of the big libraries for it, why would you need WSL at all for a Python project on Windows?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's true but I already set up most of my Python environment on WSL and mostly use WSL for programming so it was more convenient

@TimRoberts Sorry, yes, I am using VSCode inside of WSL (https://i.imgur.com/ySipw22.png)

Fixed! Selected 'Connect to WSL in New Window' in the command palette https://i.imgur.com/olQgIGj.png. I think I was accidentally running VSCode outside of WSL

VSCode is running outside WSL and use only WSL. The solution is described here. You need a plug in.

@Hermann12 Yeah I had the plugin, the issue was that I was working inside of Windows instead of using VSCode inside of WSL. Fixed now :)

I do most of my work in WSL, so I like to keep a different theme telling me which env I'm in.

Hi Jon, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)

Fixed! Selected 'Connect to WSL in New Window' in the command palette (CTRL+Shift+P on Windows) .
I think I was accidentally running VSCode in Windows instead of WSL. @Aarav made a good point of keeping a different theme for Windows vs WSL on VSCode.
Thanks for the help!
